# Flask render_template() returning "NameError: name 'app' is not defined"

Tags: python, flask

I am following the Quickstart Guide for Flask. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files 
 I'm getting this error as I follow the guide.

```
/application
/__init__.py
/templates
    /hello.html

   @app.route('/hello/')
   @app.route('/hello/<name>')
   def hello(name=None):
       return render_template('hello.html', name=name)

    >python _init_.py 
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "_init_.py", line 4, in <module>
   @app.route('/hello/')
   NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Comment: you just need to import the render_template. `from flask import Flask, render_template`

Answer (score 52):

Perhaps this?

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
```

Answer (score 28):

The only thing missing is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
```

Answer (score 16):

Look at the minimal program on the [Flask website](http://flask.pocoo.org/), especially the first two lines:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

You problem is that you haven't [imported](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) a Flask module and haven't initialized a [Flask app object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#api).

Comment: Found the issue ........ in the code the variables name and main have 2 underscores.. i was using one.

Answer (score 9):

I am surprised no one has marked this question answered. As many have suggested, I can also confirm that `from flask import Flask, render_template` solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

You need to:

```
from flask import request
```

I think its a flaw in Flask's quickstart guide.